# Using external DVD player with Nexus 7

Tags: nexus

I would like to be able to use my external DVD player with my Nexus 7 tablet, is there a plug-in for that or a mount?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if your DVD player has `USB output`, something like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvoyab75QgQ).

If you have one, you have to use an [`USB OTG cable`](https://www.google.hu/search?q=otg+cable&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=2560&bih=1315&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3voCq-eTOAhXHthQKHUKID4MQ_AUIBigB) (USB female to MicroUSB male) to connect your devices.

E.g.: As you can see in the video, it is working even without root access with a portable Samsung DVD player: [Samsung Optical Smart Hub](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/review/wifi-routers/samsung-optical-smart-hub-review-3359451/) and a Nexus 7 with stock Android.

If you DVD player hasn't USB output I think there is a very little chance to connect them to each other directly.